# I want to Execute mongoimport on a Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, macos, docker

I use Docker to develop.

`docker exec -it <My-Name> mongo`

I want to import the data to MongoDB from a JSON file, but it fails.

The command is

`mongoimport -d <db-name> -c <c-name> --file xxx.json`

What can I do?

Comment: Can you share the fail message?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With your description it seems that 
you have a datafile in json format in your host machine and you want to import this data into mongodb which is running in a container.

You can follow following steps to do so.

```
#>docker exec -it <container-name> mongo
#>docker cp xxx.json <container-name-or-id>:/tmp/xxx.json
#>docker exec <container-name-or-id> mongoimport -d <db-name> -c <c-name> --file /tmp/xxx.json
```

In the last step you have to use file path that is available in the container.

To debug more if required you can login into the container and execute the way you do on the Linux machines.

```
#>docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> sh
sh $>cat /tmp/xxx.json
sh $>mongoimport -d <db-name> -c <c-name> --file /tmp/xxx.json
```

Comment: correct command is `#>docker cp xxx.json <container-name-or-id>:/tmp/xxx.json`  Thanks

Comment: Updated in answer now, Thanks

Comment: Somehow second line ends up with `uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :`, what would be the reason?

Answer (score 18):

Run without copy file:

```
docker exec -i <container-name-or-id> sh -c 'mongoimport -c <c-name> -d <db-name> --drop' < xxx.json
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer because it has no explanation.. But it did work for me.

Comment: Failed: (Unauthorized) command drop requires authentication

Comment: with --jsonArray option

Answer (score 5):

- Step 1: Navigate to the directory where the JSON file located from your host terminal.
- Step 2: Use command "docker cp xxx.json mongo:/tmp/xxx.json” to copy the JSON file from current host directory to container "tmp" directory.
- Step 3: Navigate to container command shell by using command “docker container exec -it mongo bash”.
- Step 4:  Import the collection from "tmp" folder to container database by using command : "mongoimport --uri="`<mongodb connection uri`>"  —collection=`<c-name`> --file /tmp/xxx.json"

Comment: When down voting an answer which someone has taken the time to prepare, please also take the time to add some constructive feedback in the form of a comment. This helps people understand how the answer they provided can be improved and allows the stack overflow community to continue to develop.

Answer (score 0):

What we have:

1. mongodb running in docker container.
2. json file to import from local machine
3. mongoimport.exe on local machine

What to do to import this json file as a collection:

```
mongoimport --uri=<connection-string> --collection=<collection-name> --file=<path-to-file>
```

Example:

```
mongoimport --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/test" --collection=books --file:"C:\Data\books.json"
```

More details regarding mongoimport here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/